# When I call API by isomorphic-fetch module, looks like it doesn't get session

Tags: express, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm working with MERN stack structure and Redux, I have a problem with isomorphic-fetch module.

I would like to user info from session, but isomorphic-fetch module seems that its request is seperated from users session.

following is the view dispatches an action to get user info from session.

MainView.jsx:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../../redux/actions/actions';

class MainView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayName = 'MainView';
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.showMessageModal.message !== '') {
      this.props.dispatch(Actions.showMessageModal());
    }
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.fetchUserSession());
  }
  render() {
    const renderTemp = () => {
      if (this.props.user) {
        return <div>{ JSON.stringify(this.props.user) }</div>;
      }
    };
    return (
      <div>
        MainView
        { renderTemp() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MainView.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object,
};

function mapStateToProps(store) {
  return {
    showMessageModal: store.showMessageModal,
    user: store.user,
  };
}

MainView.propTypes = {
  showMessageModal: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainView);
```

followings are action, reducer and router.

actions.js (only related codes):

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/constants';
import Config from '../../../server/config';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const baseURL = typeof window === 'undefined' ? process.env.BASE_URL || (`http://localhost:${Config.port}`) : '';

export function getUserSession(user) {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.GET_USER_SESSION,
    user,
  };
}

export function fetchUserSession() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(`${baseURL}/api/session-user`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => dispatch(getUserSession(response.user)));
  };
}
```

reducer_user.js (combined in index reducer):

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/constants';

export const user = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.GET_USER_SESSION :
      return action.user;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

user.router.js (api router):

```
import { Router } from 'express';

router.get('/api/session-user', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.user: ' + req.user);
  res.json(req.user);
});

export default router;
```

After login, when I go to '/api/session-user' directly on browser, I can see the user info like this.

[user info on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hnnF.png)

But when I load MainView and it dispatches action, 'req.user' in user.router.js returns 'undefined'.

Please guess what the wrong is. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. 'isomorphic-fetch' wasn't setting request cookie, so it couldn't get its session from the cookie. I've changed my code in action.js as below, and it's working perfectly.

```
export function fetchUserSession() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return $.ajax({
      url: `${baseURL}/api/session-user`,
      success: (response) => {
        dispatch(getUserSession(response));
      },
    });
  };
```

I refered to this page - https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `credentials` parameter :

```
export function fetchUserSession() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(`${baseURL}/api/session-user`, {credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => dispatch(getUserSession(response.user)));
  };
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but didn't work. What does credential option function?